# Theorem by Whitney

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, manifolds

For $0<k<\infty$ and any $n$-dimensional $C^k$ manifold the maximal atlas contains a $C^\infty$ atlas on the same underlying set by a theorem due to Whitney. Could someone please point me to where I can find the theorem and a proof thereof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Morris Hirsch's *Differential Topology* text contains a proof.  I don't have the text here, but it appears fairly early in the textbook.  The key idea is in his theorem on increasing the order of differentiability of a function.

Comment: I am looking at Hirsch and I found several theorems by Whitney but none of them mentions smooth structures they are all about embeddings of $C^k$ type. Is it a consequence of one of the Whitney embedding theorems?

Comment: The embedding results imply the result about atlases.  The idea is you embed the manifold in Euclidean space, and in a tubular neighbourhood you find a $C^k$-close embedding which is a $C^\infty$-smooth manifold.  By being $C^k$-close, the bundle projection map is a diffeomorphism.